# JavaScript: Where to put alternative code when exception is thrown in try catch block?

Tags: javascript, exception, try-catch

If there is a function which executes some code which may throw exception (being unsupported in older browsers), where do I put the code which will work in older browsers but is not recommend as it is deprecated.

```js
function doSomething() {
  try {
    // Code unsupported in older browser, which may throw exception  

    return "Only on modern browser!"
  } catch (e) {
    console.error("E1")
    // Should put legacy code here?
  }

  // Or here?

  try {
    // Or here ?
  } catch (e) {
    console.error("E2")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would argue that neither of these are good approaches - instead, explicitly test for the functionality you need instead of `try`/`catch`, which captures *all* errors, which could include errors not due to an unsupported browser.

An even better approach would be to install the functionality yourself if the client happens to be running an older browser. For example, if you want to use modern functions or objects in an older browser, such as `String.prototype.includes` on Internet Explorer, [use a polyfill](https://polyfill.io/v3/) so as to run code that defines `String.prototype.includes` if it's needed. This is a much more elegant solution than, for example

```
try {
  if (str.includes('foo')) {
    // ...
} catch (e)
```

There are some things which can't be polyfilled, like Proxies and the [notification API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification). For these sorts of things, instead of `try`/`catch`, check if the object exists on the window first. For example, instead of

```
try {
  if (Notification.permission === "granted") {
    // do stuff
```

do

```
if (window.Notification) {
  if (Notification.permission === "granted") {
    // do stuff
  }
  // otherwise do other stuff if permission isn't granted
} else {
  // browser is unsupported
}
```

And the same thing for `window.Proxy` and similar.

Comment: Okay, so I should check if something like `navigator.clipboard.writeText` exists. I see.

Comment: Yep. `if (Navigator.clipboard) { // stuff } else { // unsupported browser }`